# How do you convert YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ time format to MM/DD/YYYY time format in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, datetime

For example, I'm trying to convert 2011-01-19T00:00:00Z to 01/19/2011. What's the simplest way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Time.parse` to parse a time string like that into a `Time` object. You can then use `strftime` to turn this into any string format you like:

```
require 'time'
Time.parse("2011-01-19T00:00:00Z").strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
#=> "01/19/2011"
```

Comment: The problem with using Time.parse in general is that Time formats can be confusing. For example: "01/09/2011" can be two different dates. When you know the time format it's best to use strptime since you can ensure that the results you are getting will be correct.

Comment: @Pan: That's a good point, but this particular format is handled just fine by `parse`. (Though I suppose being explicit about the format would good practice anyway).

Comment: Being explicit is fine when your date formats will never vary. As soon as they do your code 'splodes.

Comment: @theTin: But to be fair `Time.parse` can explode as well if the format changes. Or worse: it might return the wrong result.

Comment: Yes, but I wouldn't have spent all that mental energy trying to outsmart the problem only to have it flung back at me. I hate it when that happens!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Ruby Time object to parse and then re-format time and date:

```
require 'time'
time = Time.strptime("2011-01-19T00:00:00Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
=> 01/19/2011
```

If you want to take the time-zone into consideration use this line instead:

```
time = Time.strptime("2011-01-19T00:00:00Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
```

Comment: I don't think hardcoding the Z is necessarily a good idea. What if he gets a time in another time zone? Also this way the Time object will be in the local time zone, not z-time (not that it matters in this case).

Comment: I modified to take time-zone into consideration.

Comment: Another note: In ruby 1.8, you'll have to use `DateTime` instead of `Time` because `Time` does not have a `strptime` method until 1.9 (for whatever reason).

Comment: Good point, but I think DateTime is only defined in ActiveSupport.

Comment: @Pan: No, it's not. It's standard ruby (you get it when you `require "date"`). ActiveSupport just adds a bunch of methods to it.

Comment: Oh, nice. Didn't know. Thanks for the info.